# create with params don't insert new Rows to the database table

Tags: java, oracle-adf

im trying to use the createwithparm method programmatically in adf
to insert new record in the database but it doesnt works

i have db table with 2 generated values with before insert triggers
and i will pass 2 values

and this is my code

```
     OperationBinding operation = ADFUtils.findOperation("CreateWithParams"); 
     Object result = operation.execute();
```

and from the edit action binding I've referenced the 2 values i want to pass

## {pageFlowScope.userBean.investorNumber}

## {pageFlowScope.userBean.tempCode}

but nothing is inserted in the database
and there is nothing in the log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you said "nothing is inserted into the database", I have to ask: Do you understand how ADF BC(EO, VO, AM) works? When you submit a page, for example with createwithparam, it updates the EO and VOs in the ADF BC middle tier model, in memory. Nothing is written to the database. You must issue a COMMIT through the enclosing Application Module to get the data written to the db.
[This](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/13-create-with-params-169140.pdf) might help.